# What deos "Full GC" mean in GC logs, and when does "Full GC" happens?

Tags: java, jvm

I am learning how to read GC logs。

```
5429.779: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 13809K->0K(505216K)] [PSOldGen: 253802K->245481K(319488K)] 267612K->245481K(824704K) [PSPermGen: 70059K->70059K(118784K)], 0.5869143 secs] [Times: user=0.59 sys=0.00, real=0.59 secs]
```

Minor GC : a GC that happens in the young gen.
Major GC : a GC that occurs in the old gen.

What I don't understand is piece which is "Full GC".

Is Full GC mean "Major GC" or "Major GC + Minor GC" ???

And When does "Full GC" happens?